# Can the da Vinci Jr 1.0 print in 100 microns, if so how?

Tags: filament, 3d-models, pla, extruder, nozzle

I was wondering if the ***da Vinci Jr. 1.0*** can print in 100 μm layer height.

If so, how could I do this?

Comment: Hi Cates, and welcome to SE.3D Printing! Just to clarify, Do you want to print using 100 microns and are wondering if the da Vinci Jr. meets your needs (and if it doesn't, then how else would it be possible to print at 100 microns)? Or, are you asking if the da Vinci Jr. can print this fine and, if it does, how does the da Vinci Jr. manage to achieve such a layer thickness?

Answer (score 1):

I will attempt to answer your question, as it stands.

Dealing with the first part, according to the [product specifications](http://eu.xyzprinting.com/eu_en/Product/da-Vinci-1.0-Junior#spec_single), the resolution, or layer thickness, is indeed 100 μm, when printing using the **Fine** setting.

> **Resolution**
>
> Fine 0.1 mm (100 microns)
>
> Standard 0.2 mm (200 microns)
>
> Speed 0.3 mm (300 microns)
>
> Ultra Fast 0.4 mm (400 microns)

With respect to the second part of your question, *how could I do this?* You simply put the printer into **Fine** mode, and the resulting print will be printed with 100 μm thick layers.

If this is not what you wanted to ask, then please clarify your question.